# iOS: xcode 5, migrate project from xctest to senTestingKit

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, sentestingkit, xctest

I have Xcode 5.0.2.
I created new project.
New project already has test target which is based on XCTest framework.
But XCTest is not working with iOS 6.1.
But I want to test my project on iOS 6.1,
for this i believe I should migrate to SenTestingKit.

And here I have some troubles,

I imported SenTestingKit framework,
added new senTestingKit based test file.
Run my tests.

But looks like xcode still looking fot xctest files.

How to migrate correctly ?

UPDATE: All the time I have error 262): Library not loaded: /Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest

Answer (score 1):

Change the build setting "Wrapper Extension" under "Packaging" from xctest to octest, and that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had changed the "Wrapper Extension" build setting from 'xctest' to 'octest' and it still wasn't running for me.

It turns out that I also had '-Framework XCTest' as an option in 'Other Linker Flags'. Removing that got the test target building and running.

Comment: Ooo, I wonder if I didn't have to do that second part because I use cocoapods...?